# Can I find ROS topics (publishers and subscribers) only from launch file?

Tags: ros, python, ros-melodic, roslaunch, roslauch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,
I'm kinda new at ROS.
I'm trying to read a launch file in Python and to find all the nodes and topics? I can find nodes easily using roslaunch.node_args. Is finding the topics possible without executing the launch file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/346984/can-i-find-ros-topics-(publishers-and-subscribers)-only-from-launch-file?/) by [TestUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/52633/testuser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-03-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You may be able to work out some from the launch file, if any names are remapped, but other than that not from just reading the launch file, unless you are very familiar with the nodes it launches and know what topics they publish and subscribe to.

You could find it out by looking at the documentation for each of the nodes

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2020-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0